# insert batch data array?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, foreach

I want insert following data by `insert_batch` as in following example in database table (mysql):

HTML:

```
<input name="u_id[0][0]" value="76">

<input name="un[0][0]" value="1">
<input type="text" name="ue[0][0]" value="11">
<input type="text" name="up[0][0]" value="111">



<input name="u_id[1][0]" value="77">

<input name="un[1][1]" value="2">
<input type="text" name="ue[1][1]" value="22">
<input type="text" name="up[1][1]" value="222">

<input name="un[1][2]" value="3">
<input type="text" name="ue[1][2]" value="33">
<input type="text" name="up[1][2]" value="333">
```

PHP:

```
$u_id       = $this->input->post('u_id');
$un       = $this->input->post('un');
$up       = $this->input->post('up');
$ue       = $this->input->post('ue');

$data = array();
foreach ($un as $idx => $name) {
    $data[] = array(
        'u_id' => $u_id[$idx],                  
        'un' => $un[$idx],
        'up' => $up[$idx],
        'ue' => $ue[$idx],
    );
};
$this -> db -> insert_batch('units', $data);
```

I want insert they as this:

[image]

How should change php code and html code? what do i do?

Comment: You are using a framework and we don't know which one, at least give us the framework name cause i don't know where that "insert_batch" comes from, it is not standard PHP

Comment: Exact duplicate of [How can insert values array as batch in database mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790943/how-can-insert-values-array-as-batch-in-database-mysql)

Comment: @hakre - It not better that help me instead of chase me!!!!

Comment: @Mathieu Dumoulin - how is without framework?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using CodeIgniter and that the name of the database table that you want to insert to is called 'units' and that its 'id' column is autoincrement.

I am basing off my solution from CodeIgniter User Guide Version 2.0.3 using a call to a helper `($this->db->insert_string())` of the Database class.

```
foreach ($data as $row)
{
    $error_code = $this->db->insert_string('units', $row); 
}
```

Refer to http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/helpers.html

The `insert_string` function that the Database class provides appears to take an associative array, build an `INSERT` statement from the elements inside, execute it and then return a numerical error code.

Answer (score 0):

LOL, it's not pretty, but it *might* work sometimes:

```
<input name="u_id[]" value="76">

<input name="un[]" value="1">
<input type="text" name="ue[]" value="11">
<input type="text" name="up[]" value="111">



<input name="u_id[]" value="77">

<input name="un[]" value="2">
<input type="text" name="ue[]" value="22">
<input type="text" name="up[]" value="222">

<input name="un[]" value="3">
<input type="text" name="ue[]" value="33">
<input type="text" name="up[]" value="333">
```

---

```
$u_id=$this->input->post('u_id');
$un=$this->input->post('un');
$up=$this->input->post('up');
$ue=$this->input->post('ue');
for($i=0;$i<count($u_id);$i++){
    for($ii=0;$ii<count($un[$i]);$ii++){
        (count($un[$i])>1)?$unn=$un[$i][$ii+1]:$unn=$un[$i][$ii];
        (count($ue[$i])>1)?$uen=$ue[$i][$ii+1]:$uen=$ue[$i][$ii];
        (count($up[$i])>1)?$upn=$up[$i][$ii+1]:$upn=$up[$i][$ii];
        $this->db->insert('units', array(//use db insert here
            'u_id'=>$u_id[$i][0],
            'un'=>$unn,
            'ue'=>$uen,
            'up'=>$upn,
        ));
    }
}
```

I'd go so far as to suggest you not use it. But perhaps it might inspire someone to offer a better solution.

Cheers.

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Your php code not work true. i  want insert above values like this image in database table: http://i.stack.imgur.com/AjwXP.png . Where you do not understand from my question?