# How can insert values array as batch in database mysql?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, foreach

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [insert multiple rows via a php array into mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779986/insert-multiple-rows-via-a-php-array-into-mysql)

For example i have following values and want insert batch they in database, How is it?(can done it with `foreach`)

My values:

```
<input name="u_id[]" value="76">

<input name="un[0][0]" value="1">
<input type="text" name="ue[]" value="11">
<input type="text" name="up[]" value="111">



<input name="u_id[]" value="77">

<input name="un[]" value="2">
<input type="text" name="ue[]" value="22">
<input type="text" name="up[]" value="222">

<input name="un[1][2]" value="3">
<input type="text" name="ue[]" value="33">
<input type="text" name="up[]" value="333">
```

insert batch in database as:

[image]

Comment: Alicia, please don't ask the same question a second time: [insert batch data array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787959/insert-batch-data-array).